# Jupyter Hub the littlest : The server is shutting down often

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have installed Jupiter-hub-the-littlest with the tutorial on a google cloud compute engine. However, when I work for more than 1 or 2 hours on it, the server is shutting down and I have to reconnect and relaunch the server. Is there an option that I should set up to avoid this. I don't see anything very clear in the logs. Thanks for your help